# Batch file is needlessly doubling the caret character

Tags: windows, batch-file, escaping, character, caret

I need to pass a single (quoted) parameter to an exe file with a single leading caret.
I tried this:

```
@echo off
setlocal
call :RunQuery "^one two"
goto wrapup
:RunQuery
call test.exe %1
:wrapup
```

This results in

```
"^^one two"
```

But I need it to be

```
"^one two"
```

I tried

```
%~1, "%~1" and ^"%~1^"
```

without success.

The last one appears to work with an echo but not when used with the exe file:

```
call test.exe ^"%~1^"
```

In this case test.exe still seems to get two carets.

Comment: You are [not the first to discover this](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=batch+call+doubles+caret).

Comment: Thanks, the second [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12655558/strange-behavior-with-special-characters-in-arguments-of-batch-functions/12656803#12656803) actually helped me understand it better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting it to a variable before parsing it:

```
@echo off
setlocal
call :RunQuery "^one two"
goto wrapup
:RunQuery
set "escape=%1"
echo %escape%
:wrapup
```

**Outputs:**

> "^one two"