# How to remove files that are .gitignored with a recursive .../** pattern?

Tags: git

Here's the setup:

```
git init
echo "foo/**" > .gitignore
mkdir foo && touch foo/bar
git status --ignored
```

The printed status says:

```
...
Ignored files:
  (use "git add -f <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    foo/
```

Now,

```
git clean -fdX
```

... and it does nothing. `foo/bar` is still there.

Note that if I change the `.gitignore` rule from `foo/**` to just `foo/` the `-fdX` command works as expected - it deletes the `foo/` folder.

Tested with git version 2.29.1

Comment: This is probably a bug. It's not entirely clear to me what the intended behavior is with `**` and `git clean -X`, but you should send this example to the Git mailing list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr: here's a workaround for an apparent bug in `git clean -X`:

```
git ls-files -oi --exclude-standard -z | xargs -0 rm
```

which without the `-z | xargs -0 rm` is `git clean -nX` and with it is `git clean -fX`. To delete (recursively-)empty directories, `find * -depth -type d -empty -delete`.

---

On linux, after

```
mkdir t1 t2 t3
touch t1/a1 t2/a2 t3/a3
printf %s\\n 't1/**' 't2/*' 't3' >.git/info/exclude
```

the next two commands list different results:

```
git ls-files -oc|git check-ignore --stdin
git clean -nX
```

but then

```
touch t1/c1 t2/c2 t3/c3
git add -f t?/c?
git clean -nX
```

and `git clean` picks up the `t?/a?` trash.  So clean isn't recursing into wholly-ignored directories for `-X`.

edit: worse, replacing `t3` with `a3` in the ignore list and rerunning with the `c?` files gone or untracked leaves `a3` still untouched. So it's not even "wholly-ignored" directories, it's "directories with no tracked content".

Yah, something needs fixing here.

Answer (score 2):

I tested it with Git for Windows, and a first issue comes from the double-quotes:

```sh
echo "foo/**" > .gitignore
```

That will give you a `.gitignore` file with:

```
"foo/**"
```

That is enough to ignore the `foo` folder but *not* its content:
a `git check-ignore -v -- foo\bar` would return nothing.

As described in "[How do you strip quotes out of an ECHO'ed string in a Windows batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41274461/6309)", use:

```sh
echo|set /p="foo/**" > .gitignore
```

That way, you have a `.gitignore` with:

```
foo/**
```

And `git check-ignore -v -- foo\bar` does work.

```sh
$ git check-ignore -v foo/bar
.gitignore:1:foo/       foo/bar
```

In both cases though, `git clean -nfdX` does not remove anything.

Only by mentioning the file directly would git clean propose to do anything:

```sh
vonc@vonc MINGW64 /d/git/tests/ign/foo (master)
$ git clean -nX

vonc@vonc MINGW64 /d/git/tests/ign/foo (master)
$ git clean -nX bar
Would remove bar
```

To really make it work, your rule should *not* use '`**`'

```sh
echo|set /p="foo/" > .gitignore
```

Then `git clean -ndX` would work.

```sh
D:\git\tests\ign>git clean -ndX
Would remove foo/
```