# Escaping dot in if-statement with echo in Windows batch

Tags: if-statement, batch-file, echo, literals

I have a chicken-and-egg issue: I need to echo a dot in an if statement in a batch script, but the command prompt crashes, saying '. was unexpected at this time.'

Note that echoing treats everything as literal, but the if statement interprets it as incorrect due to the dot being a special character.

Adding quotation marks solves the issue, but I don't want the batch user to see the error with quotation marks. I've tried using the caret `^` character to escape it, but it's not working.

Here's my script:

```
if "%found_7zip%"=="0" (
    echo 7-Zip or 7-Zip-ZStandard not found in Program Files or Program Files (x86).
    echo Please install 7-Zip or 7-Zip-ZStandard and try again.
    pause
    exit /b 1
)
```

Your help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Yo have to escape the closing parenthesis `x86^)`

Comment: @jeb This is the correct solution. Please post an answer for this, I will mark as correct answer. I feel bad I totally missed this tiny mistake!

Comment: @AhmadAddas, it is not 'the correct solution', just one solution. Your issue was due to the premature closing of the outer parenthesis, but there are many ways to achieve a goal in scripting. For instance, you could simply remove the outer parentheses, with a one liner: ```if "%found_7zip%"=="0" echo 7-Zip or 7-Zip-ZStandard not found in Program Files or Program Files (x86).& echo Please install 7-Zip or 7-Zip-ZStandard and try again.& pause & exit /b 1```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to escape the closing parenthesis.

```
echo 7-Zip or 7-Zip-ZStandard not found in Program Files or Program Files (x86^).
```

This is necessary, because the opening parenthesis in `if "%found_7zip%"=="0" (` starts the scanning for the first closing parenthesis, independent of the position in a line.
It can escaped by a caret or by double quotes

Comment: Thanks for the catch! I totally forgot about the parentheses in Program Files (x86)!

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer [in another SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41274461/3225)

```
@echo|set /p="Please install 7-Zip or 7-Zip-ZStandard and try again."
```

Comment: Nonsense. Regardless of the value of `found_7zip`, replacing the `echo Please install…` line with the suggested code will cause the posted code to respond `. was unexpected at this time.` The problem is that the `)` in the previous line terminates the `if` statement and `cmd` will then object to the lone `.` If that `echo` line is removed, then the original code would work - the `echo|set/p` is superfluous. The solution, as suggested by jeb, is to escape (turn off the special meaning of) the `)` by preceding it with a caret `^)`

Comment: Not nonsense, but could be improved, the first line is important to escape. `<nul set /p"=7-Zip or 7-Zip-ZStandard not found in Program Files or Program Files (x86)."` And then you need an extra line feed with one more `echo(`